# javascript math does not add up

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a a form where a user can make a simple multiplication of two fields. The outcome of the equation is then placed in another input field using jquery.

```
quantity =         Number($('#quantity').val());
price =            Number($('#price').val());

subtotal = quantity * price;
```

and

```
$("input#subtotal").val(subtotal);
```

But...The numbers do not add up!!

I'm getting very strange answers with long decimals behind the comma. When running my console:

```
console.log(subtotal, price+ "x" + quantity + "=" + subtotal);
```

it literally states:

```
--> 1.07 x 1001 = 1071.0700000000002
```

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: all Javascript numbers are floating point

Comment: If you plan to use that as a number (the `var.toFixed(2).replace(/0{0,2}$/, "");` bit), you're going to have an issue with numbers like `1071.0007`.  It results in `"1071."`.  I recommend something like `Number(var.toFixed(2))`, but don't use `var`.  It's a reserved word in JS as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this floating point issue by adding:

```
myvar = myvar.toFixed(2).replace(/0{0,2}$/, "")
```

which seems to works well for price type calculations.

**EDIT:**

As Joseph Marikle indicated in the comments, this might lead to issues with numbers like 1071.0007.

```
myvar = Number(myvar.toFixed(2))
```

therefore looks to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You should not put this as an answer but as an edit to your question. As your question was *"What is going on here???"* and not *"how can I get rid of these decimals"*